# Find the missing number in the square

Tags: mathematics, number-sequence

Hopefully this is not a repost, as I couldn't find an existing one...yet:

What is the missing number?
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The answer is 27, substract the number formed by the digits on the second row from the number formed by the digits on the first row and divide by 2.

Comment: The ol multiply A by 10 and add to B trick... What do they call that again? oh right base 10... gets me everytime.

Comment: How does that apply to the 3 and 7?

Comment: 64-24=2*20, 34-28=2*3, 50-36=2*7.

Comment: oh i see what threw me off was that (6-2) = 4 (4-4)=0 when concantenated = 40 /2 = 20. Same applies for the 27. Thanks for clarification

Comment: what a short-lived question lol, nicely done Artur ;)